# When loaded with AMP :Website is not rendered correctly and unable to scroll

Tags: amp-html

I created a new website with best mobile usability in mind. So I implemented AMP. But what was meant to improve the user experience and value of the site is a userexperience-nightmare now. The site passes all validations and is more shown as an AMP-page in the search results. When I follow the link from the searchresults I can see the website, but it is not rendered correctly and much more important I does not scroll. The original page is found here: hpphysio.com/voraussetzungen-und-anerkennung/

You find the AMP-cached-site here: https://www.google.de/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=/amp/s/hpphysio.com/voraussetzungen-und-anerkennung/&ved=0ahUKEwiPov6Q9YTRAhUEN1AKHRK5Bzw4ChAWCCYwBQ&usg=AFQjCNGFQCVjh71uQLsVJ8RoO8s1XPj4IA&sig2=AUWwVpBe-X_-LkM0artRCg

What might be the problem here?

Comment: The specified page does scroll for me. What are the rendering issues you are seeing? Can you be a bit more specific with your question? It will help you get better answers :)

Comment: I was able to solve the problem. I used a selfclosing div tag.This is not valid html5. Browsers dont have a problem with it but the AMP caching have.